# How many ways that we can distribute $4$ tasks to $6$ workers if no worker can perform all four tasks?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have confusing problem about counting. I don't know how to start. Here is my problem.

How many ways that we can distribute $4$ tasks to $6$ workers?

Note: Not only distributing to all workers, the tasks can be distributed to only one, two, or three workers.

Answer:
I try solve by $6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3$ to give the task to $4$ workers. But what's next? I am sorry for my confusion.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how many ways four tasks can be distributed to six workers if no worker can perform all four tasks?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes

Comment: Is it required that every worker must have a least one task?

Answer (score 2):

If there were no restrictions, there would be six ways to assign each of the four tasks, so there would be $6^4$ ways to distribute the tasks.  However, these include the six distributions in which all four tasks are assigned to the same worker.  Hence, there are
$$6^4 - 6$$
ways to distribute the four tasks to six workers so that no worker is assigned all four tasks.